# How to repeat a number from 1 to 10000 5 times

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using numpy.

I want to repeat numbers from 0 to 10000 five times.

Let me show you a simple example below.

```
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
3
3
3
3
3

9999
9999
9999
9999
9999
10000
10000
10000
10000
10000
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with [`numpy.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```
a = np.repeat(np.arange(10001), 5)
print (a)
[    0     0     0 ... 10000 10000 10000]
```